# what does project away mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, projective-geometry

I realise I should know this but I have no idea what people mean when they say "we project away from this point" (or replace point with line, plane or whatever in projective space). What does this mean?

Comment: It means that you give this as a project to a student of yours, and let them deal with the problem! [*rimshot*](http://instantrimshot.com)

Comment: so is pro-ject dual to in-ject? when a student can't prove a lemma and has his advisor do it instead?

Comment: Suppose $L \subset \mathbf{P}^n$ is a linear subspace; consider the corresponding vector subspace $V \subset k^{n+1}$. There is a quotient map $k^{n+1} \rightarrow k^{n+1}/V$, and the corresponding rational map (not a morphism) of projective spaces is the projection away from $L$.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. If you're still around then I have a related question: let's say I have a plane P in a projective variety X, what does blowing up and projecting away from P mean? I think I now understand them both separately, but after you blow up then what? Do you project away the exceptional locus? But I guess it might not be linear, no?

Comment: Asal's comment is a great intrinsic explanation:+1. I have added a less canonical, more concrete,  answer so as to have another perspective (!)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: thanks! I tried to keep it clean, but reading your answer, mine feels somewhat lacking...

Comment: I feel like both answers are useful: one is intrinsic, the other is geometric.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $L\subset \mathbb P^n$ is a linear subspace of dimension $l$ and $M\subset \mathbb P^n$ is a linear subspace of dimension $m=n-l-1$ such that $L\cap M=\emptyset$, the projection from $L$ onto $M$ is the morphism $\mathbb P^n\setminus L\to M$ sending $p$ to the unique point of intersection $M\cap \overline {pL}$ of $M$ with the linear subspace generated by $p$ and $L$.

This is quite close to the way Renaissance painters invented projective geometry: they projected the three-dimensional world from their eye, the zero-dimensional $L$, onto their two-dimensional canvas $M$.
How not to be nostalgic about  a time when projective geometry meant the art of  the likes of Della Francesca, Brunelleschi, Donatello or Alberti?
[Please, excuse the lyric tone: I'm just back from a holiday  in Florence ...]

**Edit: a concrete computation**
As an attempt to answer carmelo's question in his comment, let me make an explicit computation. 
Consider $l=[0:0:1]\in \mathbb P^2$ (with coordinates $x:y:z$) and let us project onto the line $M$ of equation $z=0$ .
We get the map $f:\mathbb P^2\setminus \{l\}\to M:[x:y:z]\mapsto [x:y:0]$, a rational map from $\mathbb P^2$ to $M$ which cannot be extended regularly through $l$.

However if we blow up $l$ we get the variety $\tilde {\mathbb P^2}\subset \mathbb P^2\times \mathbb P^1$ defined by the condition $([x:y:z][u:v])\in \tilde {\mathbb P^2}$ iff $xv=yu$ (where $\mathbb P^1$ has coordinates $u:v$).
The rational map $f$ now extends to the regular morphism  $$\tilde f:\tilde {\mathbb P^2} \to M:([x:y:z],[u:v])\mapsto [u:v:0]$$
The indeterminacy of $f$ at $l$ has been resolved by blowing up the point  $l$ to the copy of $\mathbb P^1$ formed  by  all the pairs $([0:0:1],[u:v])\in \tilde {\mathbb P^2}$

Comment: I've been to florence many times (although I've never visited the Uffizi), I decided to excuse your lyric tone. Do know what is meant by "blowing up P and projecting away" as I asked in my last comment above? thanks

Comment: Dear carmelo, if we take the simplest case where we project from a point $l=L$ in $\mathbb P^2$ onto a  line $M$ not passing through $l$, then blowing up $l$ will give us a new variety $\tilde {\mathbb P^2}$ and a morphism $\tilde f:\tilde  {\mathbb P^2}\to M$ extending $f:\mathbb P^2\setminus l\to M$. So blowing up permits us to have a well defined morphism at the cost of replacing the point $l$ by a projective line $P$: the rational map  $f$ didn't know where to send $p$ and the solution is to send the different points of that projective line $P$ to different points of $M$.An ingenious idea!

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your time. Now I need to concretely understand what's going on in the case I'm interested in!

Comment: My pleasure, carmelo.